# Grails pagination not working as expect when using a template

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to load grails pagination asynchronously, I have the following code in a gsp file

```
<div id="phrase-pagination">
 <g:render template="phraseCount" model="[params:params]"/>
</div>
<script>
 $("#phrase-pagination").load("/dashboard/getPhrasePageCount");
</script>
```

Here is the grails template file
<g:paginate controller="dashboard" action="result" total="${phraseCount ?: 0}" params="${_params}" next=" " prev=" "/>

Here is the groovy method that is called asynchronously

def getPhrasePageCount(){
int countyResult = getPhrasePageCount()
render(view: '_phraseCount', model: [phraseCount: countyResult, _params: _params])
}

The pagination is loaded with the data, but when I click on the next page, the current page does not update. This means I am not able to click on the previous page. What am I missing?

Comment: In your controller action you have a model defined like `model: [phraseCount: countyResult, _params: _params]`.  The value associated with the `_params` key is `_params`.  Was that value intended to be `params`?  I understand that you are making up your own key for the map which would be anything, but the value has to refer to something and it isn't clear from your code what `_params` is.

Comment: def _params is a class scope variable which is updated by params in another method within the file

Comment: In your GSP you are `<g:render template="phraseCount" model="[params:params]"/>` which references `params`, not `_params`.  I can't reproduce the problem you are having but It is difficult to follow what the issue is.  If you can file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and link to a sample app that demonstrates the behavior, we will investigate.  I am sorry for the trouble.